# Alexa service response contains "Speechlet response" which contains an extra card, unsure why?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I've created my first test alexa skill, all it should do is make Alexa insult you. (I know this has already been created but this is just a test)
I've been following a tutorial, but now when I open the skill on my echo the response I get is "Sorry, something went wrong". 
The code that is being invoked is

this.emit(":tellWithCard", speechOutput, SKILL_NAME, randomInsult);

And this is the service response I get on the Service Simulator:

```
    {
      "version": "1.0",
      "response": {
        "outputSpeech": {
          "ssml": "<speak> Nah shut up, you bad little weapon </speak>",
          "type": "SSML"
        },
        "card": {
          "content": "Nah shut up, you bad little weapon",
          "title": "Insulter"
        },
        "speechletResponse": {
          "outputSpeech": {
            "ssml": "<speak> Nah shut up, you bad little weapon </speak>"
          },
          "card": {
            "content": "Nah shut up, you bad little weapon",
            "title": "Insulter"
          },
          "shouldEndSession": true
        }
      },
      "sessionAttributes": {}
    }
```

In the tutorial I followed the speechlet response was not in the service response, does anybody know why it is now included within the response for me? I am unsure whether there is an error in my code or if there is a change to how the Lambda functions work. This is the responses on cloudwatch:

```
    21:12:48
    START RequestId: 4085e037-b9c9-11e7-b5e8-23df701a71f2 Version: $LATEST
    
    21:12:48
    2017-10-25T21:12:48.029Z    4085e037-b9c9-11e7-b5e8-23df701a71f2    
    Warning: Application ID is not set
    
    21:12:48
    END RequestId: 4085e037-b9c9-11e7-b5e8-23df701a71f2
    
    21:12:48
    REPORT RequestId: 4085e037-b9c9-11e7-b5e8-23df701a71f2  Duration: 0.68 
    ms  Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Us
```

This is my index.js code:

```
"use strict";

//Variables
var Alexa = require("alexa-sdk");
var SKILL_NAME = "Insulter";
var APP_ID = "";

//List of insults
var INSULT_LIST = [
    "Nah shut up, you bad little weapon",
    "Sample insult 2",
    "Sample insult 3"
];


//Setup
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback){
    var alexa = Alexa.handler(event,context);
    alexa.APP_ID = APP_ID;
    alexa.registerHandlers(handlers);
    alexa.execute();
}

var handlers = {
    'LaunchRequest': function(){
        this.emit('GetInsult');
    },
    'GetInsultIntent': function() {
        this.emit('GetInsult');
    },
    'GetInsult' : function() {
        var insultIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*INSULT_LIST.length);
        var randomInsult = INSULT_LIST[insultIndex];

        //Output
        var speechOutput = randomInsult;

        this.emit(":tellWithCard", speechOutput, SKILL_NAME, randomInsult);
    },
    'AMAZON.HelpIntent' : function() {
        var speechOutput = "You can say give me an insult, or, you can say exit.";
        var reprompt = "What can I help you with?";
        this.emit(":ask", speechOutput, reprompt);
    },
    'AMAZON.StopIntent' : function() {
        this.emit(":tell","Goodbye!");
    },
    'AMAZON.CancelIntent' : function() {
        this.emit(":tell","Goodbye!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the Lambda logs from cloudwatch?

Comment: These are the logs, there is several but its just this over and over again because i've tried it so many times

Comment: I couldn't find any error in the log. Can you add a console.log in the beginning and end of your lambda?

Comment: I've added my code to the question, maybe that's easier to see if there are any errors. This is my index.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've resolved the problem I was having. It turns out the issue was that I was on English (U.S) despite the fact I have a UK Alexa, and changing things on the amazon developer console to English (U.K) everything worked as expected. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

The fourth parameter `(according to amazon is this.emit(':tellWithCard', speechOutput, cardTitle, cardContent, imageObj);)` is an `imageObj`, you are trying to put a speech string there, which I believe is why your alexa is crashing. Place an image there or remove it altogether.

Comment: I only have 3 parameters after the ":tellWithCard", i've actually tried this with just ":tell" but my response always has this extra "speechletResponse" within itself, I have not seen this appear in any examples I have followed and believe this might be causing the problem, unsure how to stop it though.